# System.Net.Webclient only download 81.4 MB (85,363,075 bytes)

Tags: powershell, webclient, windows-server-2008-r2

```
[string] $fileName = "en_sql_server_2008_r2_developer_x86_x64_ia64_dvd_522665.iso"
[string] $url = "http://installers.abc/iso/$filename"
[string] $tempPath = "c:\balpreet"

function Download-Iso {
  Param(
    [string] $FileName,
    [string] $Url,
    [string] $destinationFolder 
  )

  [string] $destination = Join-Path -Path $tempPath -ChildPath $fileName 
  write-host "downloading from : $url to $destination"
    $client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
    $client.DownloadFile( $Url, $destination )

}

Download-Iso -FileName $fileName -Url $url -DestinationFolder = $tempPath
```

I'm trying to download 4.07 GB (4,380,329,984 bytes) ISO from remote location accessible over http.

**Windows 7** : It download complete 4.07 GB file.

**Windows Server 2008 R2** :
It download only 81.4 MB (85,363,075 bytes) and pretend to completed the download. Code is not throwing any error, but not downloading complete file as well.

Any clue why?

Comment: Is it possible that you're running out of disk space on the C drive on the Windows Server 2008 R2 system?

Comment: Does this happen with other files as well? I've also had issues with some corporate firewalls. At my work the "smart" firewall sometimes thinks that certain files are viruses, and kills the connection... and it always seems to kill it at the same point as well. My only way around it was to download the file from home, and bring it in on a USB key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was internal network proxy which was for some reason dropping the request after 81.4 MB (85,363,075 bytes) were transfered. But the weird thing is **webclient was not throwing any exception and was pretending that download was successful.**

Fix is to null the proxy so request is processed without going through proxy.

```
$client.proxy=$null  # get rid of proxy
$client.DownloadFile( $Url, $destination )
```